# Can't access HDFS when Hadoop cluster kerberized

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, ambari

I successfully kerberized a test Hortonworks cluster. Ambari created keytabs for the services and they are all started. There is HA for namenodes. Standby namenode starts fast, the Active namenode takes much longer. Namenode UI shows that everything is correct. Can login by using kerberos.
Namenodes are **nn1.zim.com** and **nn2.zim.com**

What can be wrong with this configuration?
Login as hdfs, load keytab with kinit -kt. On list HDFS attempt I get this error:

> [root@nn1 hdfs]# hdfs dfs -ls /
>   18/12/02 16:18:22 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the                                     server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSE                                    xception: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Ker                                    beros tgt)]
>   18/12/02 16:18:22 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: java.io.IOException: Failed                                     on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS                                     initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechani                                    sm level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "nn1.                                    zim.com/192.168.50.10"; destination host is: "nn2.zim.com":8020; , while invokin                                    g ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over nn2.zim.com/192.168.50.11:                                    8020 after 1 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 1123ms.

Kerberos principal for hosts are:

> nn1.zim.com/192.168.50.10@ZIM.COM
>   nn1.zim.com@ZIM.COM
>   nn2.zim.com/192.168.50.11@ZIM.COM
>   nn2.zim.com@ZIM.COM
>   host/nn1.zim.com@ZIM.COM
>   host/nn2.zim.com@ZIM.COM

The krb5.cfg:

> [logging]  default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
>   kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
>   admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
>
> [libdefaults]  dns_lookup_realm = false
>   ticket_lifetime = 24h 
>   renew_lifetime = 7d
>   forwardable = true
>   rdns = false  default_realm =
>   ZIM.COM
>   default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
>
> [realms]  ZIM.COM = {
>   kdc = kb.zim.com
>   admin_server = kb.zim.com
>   }
>
> [domain_realm]
>   .zim.com = ZIM.COM
>   zim.com = ZIM.COM

Comment: Back to basics: log in as a Linux **user** and create a Kerberos ticket for **user** principal e.g. `kinit ducon@ZIM.COM`

Comment: The default Kerberos credentials cache is `/tmp/krb5cc_`<id-of-current-user> so don't mess around with root or any other system / shared account.

Comment: Recommended reading: _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"_ by Steve Loughran (HortonWorks). But read about Kerberos basics first.

Comment: I've updated the question with the solution.

Comment: better add solution as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: The two kerberos principals for each host have to be created: FQDN and short. I've created only FQDN (nn1.zim.com) - this was the cause of the issue. After creation of the second principal (nn1), everything started to work.

When you work with Active Directory, both types of the principals would be created automatically on AD Computer object creation.